# Laravel redirecting path to root directory

Tags: php, laravel

Hello am actually trying to setup laravel app on shared hosting. to simulate this i simply trying opening project directly from public folder, instead to doing PHP artisan serve.
but i don't know why am redirecting to root directory
for ex
here is my URL
http://localhost/sar/public/

but when i try to access Add-Subject by using this.

```
<a href="/Add-subject">Subjects</a>
```

am redirected to this URL
http://localhost/Add-subject

but i want URL like this : http://localhost/sar/public/Add-subject

Comment: Use the [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag

Comment: try to write add-subject  without /add-subject and tell me what happen and i will explain why